# Distributed cache service instance port 22233 is already in use

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, distributedcache

We are supporting SharePoint 2013 live environment, with distributed cache service instance is running fine,

Suddenly received the Event viewer with cache cluster is down and restart it.

I restarted the cache cluster and received the error message with timeout error in starting the app fabric cache service.

I did `remove-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance` and later tried

add-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance.

Receiving the below error --

> Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance :
>   ErrorCode:SubStatus:TCP port 22233 is
>   already in use.

i checked port status using `net-stat -a -b and the port 22233` status is showing established with `distributedcacheservice.exe`

How can i resolve this issue.  Please help.

I am bit worrying as the incorrect distributed cache configuration may cause farm configuration database corruption,

Answer (score 1):

I would start this way, Run the below command:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

Check how many servers return and whats their status? Is is required servers already in the list and status is up. Run this

```
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
```

If status of all servers are up, then i think you are fine. Otherwise

Run `Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` server complaining. Now wait once the Server compeltely removed from the cluster. Run this `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`

Comment: I tried  Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance and then Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance but again getting the error message 'Port 22233' is already in use.  I removed the distributed cache instance again and checked ports status using netstat command and could see port 22233 with status established and using distributedcacheservice.exe.  I checked the same in Test environment with remove-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance and port 22233 is not showing in netstat list. will reboot the server  solve this port releasing issue.

Comment: After running remove commmand,run the get-spservicesinstajce command and what's the output?

Comment: the output of get-spserviceinstance is blank and the distributed cache service instance is deleted and i checked it in manage services in central admin. I checked the port 22233 status and it is still showing listening associated with distributedcacheservice.exe in netstat output.

Comment: i opened task manager and could still see distributedcache.exe running after ran remove-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance. Can i end the process in task manager or it should not be?

Comment: Try this script $instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService”
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$s.delete()

Comment: i ran the above command from your comments and delete method is throwing exception as service instance is not existing. Also distributedcacheservice.exe is running in task manager and port is still listening. Under services.msc, the appfabriccache service is stopeed but it state is in manual mode not moved to disabled.

Comment: Start the app fabric service from service.msc then again run above command

Comment: the issue resolved post sever reboot. Thanks for your help.